# Not able to get Android app onto any activity besides MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm developing an Android app and I am planning to have a MainActivity that will give two options, one will lead to a Responder Activity and one to a Patient activity, depending on the appropriate button they press.

However, when the app compiles I can't get it to the next activity. Here's a snippet of my code. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mResponder, mPatient;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPatient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.patient);
    mResponder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.responder);

    mResponder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResponderLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });

    mPatient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PatientLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are your click handlers being triggered? (Add a breakpoint/log statement) Are DriverLoginActivity and CustomerLoginActivity registered in your manifest? Any errors in logcat?

Comment: Oops, copied the wrong code into my question from a different project. I've added the right code now

Comment: Seems functionally about the same, so I would still say my previous questions are the first things to check

Comment: you're not getting any error in the logs?

Comment: is your app crashing after button click? if yes then post your crash logs

Answer (score -2):

remove finish in both methods .